# Should I directly talk to my boss if I don't like what he did?

Tags: professionalism

I am leading a team of 16 engineers (4 sub teams.) We have been doing a great job, deliver what business needs on time. Two months ago, we were asked to deliver a couple new features in a short time (40% of the estimated time.) This is a hard deadline and it was a pure business decision.

I had serious talks with my team and explained it to everyone that we really needed this done. We removed features we did not need, planned everything in steps, and delivered everything as plan.

A couple days ago, which is a month before the deadline. There was a feature that I did not explain it to anyone and my boss knew that when he talked to us. He was so pissed about this and talked to me in a not-so-nice way in front of my team. (We spent less than 30 making that change)

I know it was my fault and I have plan to mitigate this in the future. Anyway, I still have a hard feeling toward him and I really don't like this. I was tempted to talk to him because I know if I don't do that I might have this feeling hanging there for a while.

Should I talk to my boss and tell him that I don't like what he did? Or it's better to only discuss about it and tell him my plans to mitigate this in the future.

Answer (score 10):

> There was a feature that I did not explain it to anyone and my boss
>   knew that when he talked to us. He was so pissed about this and talked
>   to me in a not-so-nice way in front of my team.
>
> I know it was my fault and I have plan to mitigate this in the future.
>   Anyway, I still have a hard feeling toward him and I really don't like
>   this. I was tempted to talk to him because I know if I don't do that I
>   might have this feeling hanging there for a while.
>
> Should I talk to my boss and tell him that I don't like what he did?

It probably depends on your relationship with your boss.

If you have a good relationship, then it makes complete sense to tell him privately something like "I understand your criticism, but I'd prefer that we discuss this kind of thing privately, rather than getting angry in front of my team."

If your relationship is poor or adversarial, and your boss is the type who never takes constructive criticism well, then that sort of move might provoke more anger. In that case you might be better off to just explain your plan to mitigate this sort of problem in the future and hope for the best.

Answer (score -1):

So he pegged you down a notch or two in front of the class.

**Get over it.**

He probably overreacted and / or had a bad day or was pissed at you.

It could have well been to ensure that the others fall in line.

**But frankly, it's his prerogative as long as he remains civil.**

*That doesn't mean you can't defend yourself in the moment and / or admit a mistake if it was one.*

If this happens again you certainly could let him know privately that you don't apreciate him talking you down like that in front of your team as it diminishes your ability to get results from them.

How this is received depends on your relationship, professional standing within the company, his opinion of you and his personality.

Comment: _in front of the class_ - this is extremely unprofessional and I find your answer overall on the wrong side because you seem to be thinking the same way as that boss that has the necessity to piss at people in front of other one to show how _great_ he is. -1

Comment: @red-shield did that hurt feelings?I'm not on the boss's side but it's within his right and obligation to discipline employees if they did something wrong.if others benefit from that,it's just fine to do it right there in front of them.it's also a common tactic to let a lead bare the brunt of managements anger to make sure,lower ranking employees will NOT make the same mistake.See,I'm an objective adult who lives in the real world and knows,OP could've faced much more severe consequences (appropriate and inappropriate).it sucks but it's hardly worth going toe to toe after the first occurence.

Comment: This is not right because everyone wants to be respected and talking like this to someone in front of other people can destroy their image. Is this what you want? This is wrong. You should talk to him in person, privately otherwise you'll always be seen as the a...hole who destroys others publicly. If you did this to me, you're forever my enemy and I would do everything to make your pay for it. This is how this works. If you want people to respect you, you must do the same.

Comment: [3 Reasons to Never Criticize Your Employees in Public](https://www.fool.com/careers/2018/03/28/3-reasons-to-never-criticize-your-employees-in-pub.aspx) - this is just the tip of the iceberg

Comment: @red-shield chill out bro.I said I don't agree with what he did but he can.Now,remember,I also said if he remains civil.Besides,we have no idea what was said,only that OP didn't like it.I found amusing that you said you'd start a vendetta against your boss and make sure he'd pay.(actually you addressed me,but I don't take it personally)anyways,good luck with your feud against your boss after he fired you for having a snowflake meltdown.your link was hilarious btw.respect is earned and while decent behavior and good manners are key,the world is not a cocoon nor a safe place.we all deal with it.